# how should i store data in mongodb / nosql?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

I am writing a large social network on node.js and mongodb (mongoose module).
That mean there will be many users and large data in database.

I have created user registration and now i need to allow users write private messages to each other.

**Questions:**

1) how should i store data about sending private messages?
i have thought 2 ways:

*first*

```
var schemaUser = new mongoose.Schema({
    i: Number,
    ...
    message: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Message' }
});
var schemaMessage = new mongoose.Schema({
    m: [{
        f: Number, // value i from schemaUser, means from user
        m: String, // message
        d: { type: Date, default: Date.now } // date
    }]
});
module.exports = {
    User: db.model('User', schemaUser),
    Message: db.model('Message', schemaMessage)
}
```

In this way every user has `message` field to `Message` table, where he has only one collection `m`, where in array stores all messages.

*second*

I store in `Messages` all messages like this:

```
var schemaMessage = new mongoose.Schema({
    t: Number, // means to what user this messages sent
    f: Number, // value i from schemaUser, means from what user message sent
    m: String, // message
    d: { type: Date, default: Date.now } // date
});
```

All messages are mixed in one table. But as i understood, the disadvantage of this method is that there are might be more than million private messages in database, and that is why the speed and performance to find messages `from` user and `to` user was sent will be bad.
when on *first* method all messages are in array.

So, which way should i choose or any other ideas?

2) I have array like on first method: `var arr = []`
question: how many objects can i put in `arr`? what is the size of `arr`? for example, if i push something like `arr.push({t: #, f: #, m: 'message...'})`?

Comment: Why did you pick MongoDB?

Comment: I read much about databases and deciced, that MongoDB is the best for my aims (node.js+socket.io+express). What should i use instead to your opinion? :)

Comment: I'm not sure that MongoDB is a good fit for a "social" network type messaging system. Low volume, it could work, but for high volume, the fact that there aren't joins can make data collation for presentation challenging from a performance perspective without lots of caching, etc. A lot of design would need to be done before any code is written. :)

Comment: What db would you recommend instead MongoDB? MySQL? Anyway i wrote on MongoDB a lot and read that MongoDB goes nuts, everyone should use it)

Comment: You can use what you want, and I'd not want to recommend a specific platform without a lot more details (and StackOverflow isn't a good place for these types of discussions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, MongoDB encourages embedding of data instead of relations, because this allow to get all relevant data with a single query. There is, however, an exception: MongoDB doesn't like documents which grow indefinitely.

When a document gradually grows over its lifetime, the database has to reallocate hard drive space frequently. This slows down writes and leads to database fragmentation. Also, documents have a hardcoded size limit of 16MB (mostly to discourage document growth). A user accumulating more and more private messages during his membership would be a good example of indefinite growth.

In your situation it is important to identify your most frequent use-case. How are you going to present private messages to the user? Will they see all messages they ever got with their full text on one long HTML page? Unlikely.

You likely want to list them like an email inbox with sender and headline, and show the actual content when the user clicks on them. When that's the case, you should just store an array with this meta-data, and store the actual content in a different collection which is queried when the user actually clicks on a message. You still have growth that way, but it would be less of a problem, because you have a lot less data per message stored in the user document.

It's also likely that you only want to show those messages on each normal page impression which are unread, while a complete list of old private messages is a special page which is used less often. When that's the case, you would only embed the unread messages in the User document, and move them to another collection after they are read. This prevents document growth because most users will keep their list of unread messages low.

Comment: thank you for answer. in a few words, how should i be? choose second way to store messages in db?

Comment: @sirjay that depends on how you use your database. There is no "one right way" for document-oriented databases [like we have for relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (or maybe there is one, but we haven't figured it out yet). Find out which queries are the most frequent ones and optimize for those.